# Java: Match City Regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm using the following regex to match city:

```
[a-zA-Z]+(?:[ '-][a-zA-Z]+)*
```

The problem is it not only matches the city but also part of the street name.

How can I make it match only the city (such as Brooklyn and Columbia City)?

UPDATE:

The data is represented in 1 line of text (each address will be fed to regex engine separately):

```
    2778 Ray Ridge Pkwy, 
Brooklyn NY 1194-5954



1776 99th St,
Brooklyn NY 11994-1264

 1776 99th St,
Columbia City  OR 11994-1264
```

Comment: isn't the city "NY Brooklyn" and not "Brooklyn"?

Comment: No, the city is "Brooklyn". NY is the state

Comment: My advice, explain us your data format, then someone would probably come with a solution

Comment: There seems to be NO unique pattern at all here...

Comment: You can't do this with only regex, there's no pattern here. You need a dictionary of cities then parse the words and lookup the dictionary whether the word it's a city or not.

Comment: .. and  you got an answer, told you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following approach: match the words from the beginning of the string till the first occurrence of 2 uppercase letters followed with the ZIP (see the look-ahead `(?=\s+[A-Z]{2}\s+\d{5}-\d{4})` below):

```
^[A-Za-z]+(?:[\s'-]+[A-Za-z]+)*(?=\s+[A-Z]{2}\s+\d+-\d+)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yR4jQ0/6)

The regex:

- `^` - then starts looking from the beginning
- `[A-Za-z]+` - matches a word
- `(?:[\s'-]+[A-Za-z]+)*` - matches 0 or more words that...
- `(?=\s+[A-Z]{2}\s+\d+-\d+)` - are right before a space + 2 uppercase letters,  space, 1 or more digits, hyphen and  1 or more digits.

If the ZIP (or whatever the numbers stand for) is optional, you may just rely on the 2 uppercase letters:

```
^[A-Za-z]+(?:[\s'-]+[A-Za-z]+)*(?=\s+[A-Z]{2}\b)
```

Note that `\b` in `\s+[A-Z]{2}\b` is a word boundary that will force a non-word (space or punctuation or even end of string) to appear after 2 uppercase letters.

Just do not forget to use double backslash in Java to escape regex special metacharacters.

Here is a [Java code demo](http://ideone.com/GVfNNC):

```
String s = "Brooklyn NY 1194-5954";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z]+(?:[\\s'-]+[A-Za-z]+)*(?=\\s+[A-Z]{2}\\b)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); 
}
```

Comment: You did not test with `m` option. See my updated demo. You said you have separate lines, so the `m` option is only for demo. I will provide the Java code now.

Comment: It should work as expected I think. I do not know why your question is downvoted, but recently, there's been a lot of such meaningless downvotes :(

Comment: Ah, Thanks! I am reviewing it and will accept shortly. Thanks for comforting words, I don't know why my question was downvoted either. Your a good man :)

Comment: I updated the answer to support names with spaces, single apostrophes and hyphens. Note that the single apostrophe can also be represented with a curly apos, `’`. You might need to add it to the `[\s'-]` character class.

Answer (score 1):

OK.. I think I got it after hrs of tweaking and testing. May be helpful for someone else. This did the trick:

```
(?<=\n)[a-zA-Z]+(?:[ '-][a-z]+)* ?[A-Z]?[a-z]+
```

Comment: It works on the current multiline input, but if you test separate strings, you'd need to get rid of the look-behind and use `^`. It does not match `New York City` in `New York City CA 1194-5954`, but the general idea is valid.

Answer (score 0):

In case all your data is like in your example in the question, the pattern in your data is everything from the comma after the street to minimum 2 uppercase letters which represents the state.

This pattern matches the pattern as described and selects a group which should represent the city:

```
,\s+([a-zA-Z\s]*)[A-Z]{2,}?\s+
```

Comment: This includes the comma and state in the match

Comment: It's matched, but the capture group (everything between the parenthesis) will only match the city. You can then select just that group: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html

Comment: Sure but therefore you have the group: ([a-zA-Z\s]*). The regex matcher of java allows you to get a group out of the matched text.

Comment: matcher.group(...) should get you the city from your data: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html